# Protocol Documentation for Simulator

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

(Forwarded from [DRC Forum](http://forum.theroboticschallenge.org/index.php?topic=7.0))

Hi All,

I am new to Gazebo/ROS, and the DRC Simulator, and I am looking for documentation on the TCP/IP Protocol for communicating with the DRC Robot Simulator. I am assuming the SDF file is like a Rosetta Stone for the DRC Robot hardware, however, some API documentation on defined Data Inputs and Outputs, IP Address, Port number, and other details for the DRC Simulator would be super helpful. Please help!

Sincerely,

Aaron

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/138/protocol-documentation-for-simulator/) by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1414 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The ROS API for the drcsim will appear in the [User Guide](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/UserGuide#ROS_APIs).  We're aiming to fill that in with the drcsim 2.0 release.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0